# How to setup SVN on my Computer

Tags: windows, svn

How do I setup SVN on my computer? I dont mean a local one. I have friends in other countries and I want to setup SVN on my computer so that they can upload and download work to my computer.

I have installed VisualSVN Server, and my URL is `https://NAME:8443/svn` but when when I try to connect to it using tortoiseSVN, it wont let me.

I am doing this on Windows 7(x64)

Comment: why not use a public code hosting site, ie github

Comment: `I dont mean a local one.` and then you continue about how you want a local one, please watch out how you use your terms because it could end up really confusing someone. Please consider that there are free private solutions like Bitbucket if your ISP does not allow you to set up a SVN server.

Answer (score 2):

Can you connect to that URL with a web browser? If not, your server isn't configured correctly, or is firewalled. If it can, then the problem is probably on the client side.

If it's the client side, perhaps TortoiseSvn is unhappy with a self-signed SSL certificate (which I'm assuming you're using). The command line svn client program will prompt you if it doesn't like the certificate and let you accept it, but I don't know whether Tortoise will. Once the regular command line client accepts a certificate, TortoiseSvn will use the same configuration option and accept it.